# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable Python 3

Tags: python, typeerror

I keep getting TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
wondering why

```
from math import log

class Logarithm(object):

    def __init__(self, base = 0, number= 0):
        self.base = float(base)
        self.number = float(number)

        the_logarithm = log(self.base[self.number])

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Your log = {}'.format(the_logarithm)
```

Comment: also, it should be `self.the_logarithm` (both in `__init__` and in `__str__`).

Answer (score 2):

Because of this:

```
log(self.base[self.number])
```

What are you trying to accomplish here? `self.base` is a float so this statement is being evaluated as "the `number`th element of `base`", which Python can't do.

Answer (score 2):

Cameron Sparr's answer is correct.

You should probably re-check the `help(math.log)`.
It is

```
log(x[, base]) -> the logarithm of x to the given base.
```

meaning that the base argument is optional (defaults to `e`)
and not `log(x[base])`